# Chrome and char value 26

Tags: web-services, google-chrome

I calling a webservice which returns a string. This works fine in Internet Explorer, but when i try in chrome i can this error:

*This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 219150: PCDATA invalid Char value 26

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.*

Sounds like Chrome doesn't like character which is in the return string.

Anyone who can help me with this?